# What are some recommended training resources for Windows Server 2008, IIS 7.5 and SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, sql-server-2008-r2

My employer is starting a project to migrate one of our application server stacks from an open-source stack based on JBoss and PostgreSQL on Linux to a Microsoft stack powered by IIS 7.5, SQL Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2008. Political discussions aside, what are some recommended training resources for brining a UNIX administrator up to speed on administration functions in this ASP.NET hosting stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start is [www.iis.net](http://www.iis.net).  That's for pull information, in other words if you know what you're looking for, you can find the answer.  It doesn't necessarily lead you into the foundational topics needed to transfer your knowledge to this stack.  It's a great place to start though with resources, forums and links to more.

I started a weekly video blog series at the beginning of the year.  It's only 14 weeks in at this point but it covers some topics that you may find useful.  At ~10 minutes a week, it's meant to be a quick way to touch on a broad range of topics, focused on the IIS administrator.  Here's a [link to the videos](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/tags/Web+Pro+Series/default.aspx).